# SQLAlchemy how to query across multiple relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say we have a database representing a dance school. There are users that can be teachers of lessons and they can have carnets which hold the information to which lessons they have access to. Carnets and lesson are bound together with associative table. Given the following model:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    teaches = relationship('Lesson', back_populates='teacher')
    carnets = relationship('Carnet', back_populates='user')


class Lesson(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'lessons'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    teacher_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    teacher = relationship('User', back_populates="teaches")
    carnets = relationship('Carnet', secondary='carnets_lessons', back_populates='lessons')


class Carnet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'carnets'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = relationship('User', back_populates='carnets')
    lessons = relationship('Lesson', secondary='carnets_lessons', back_populates='carnets')


class CarnetLesson(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'carnets_lessons'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    carnet_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('carnets.id'))
    lesson_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('lessons.id'))
```

How can I construct an ORM query that would select all users from a lesson with given id (based on information from carnets assigned to lesson)?
I'm getting completely lost with `join` method as it's joining `User.teaches` with `Lesson.teacher` and it's definitely not what I want.